# Issue with mysql query cant seem to find out why

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to upload a user id to my database on a recipe website im making for a uni project,

the insert code was working perfectly till i added the `$_SESSION` to the insert statement.

This is what my code looks like currently:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `recipename` (mealname,ingredients,hours,minutes,recipe,imagepath,userID)VALUES ('$mealname', '$ingredients','$hours','$minutes','$recipe','$image'," . $_SESSION['userid'] . ")";

mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Insert failed. ". mysqli_error($db_server));
```

The echo:

```
INSERT INTO recipename(mealname,ingredients,hours,minutes,recipe,imagepath,userID) VALUES ('misbah', 'ss','1','1','s','','')
```

========================================================================
And this is the error i keep getting back..

Insert failed. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

I'm still new to code so am pretty baffled by it..

Comment: This is the error** Insert failed. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: what is the value of $_SESSION['userid'] at the time of the insert ?

Comment: @misdigest From the looks of this, you're treating everything but the userid as a character type of some sort. What are the actual datatypes of your columns? Additionally, make sure everything is escaped. One ' or " in your character types could throw your query off. Use prepared statements.

Comment: Holy [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), Batman!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is Session['userid'] just numbers? If it contains text as well, then your query is missing quotes before and after it, like the rest of your variables.

However, before that, try to echo `$_SESSION['user_id']` before you try the query to see if it works. If so, then like I said before, add the quotes. And we found out that your query was not working because you never had a value in your Session tag and therefore, quotes were needed to correct the end of your statement. The problem now is finding out where or what happened to your `$_SESSION['user_id']` value.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `recipename` (mealname,ingredients,hours,minutes,recipe,imagepath,userID)VALUES ('$mealname', '$ingredients','$hours','$minutes','$recipe','$image','" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "')";
```

Comment: $_SESSION['userid'] is just numbers, will try adding the quotes and echoing out $_SESSION['userid']

Comment: Another thing I would try is echoing your query before sending it to mysqli `echo $query` and then reply here with what it says. Also th guy above completely just copied what I said HAHAH

Comment: I've added the quotes and this has solved the issue so thank you but it's still returning the userid value as null on the database..

Comment: Please echo out your query for me and post it here to see.

Comment: INSERT INTO `recipename`(mealname,ingredients,hours,minutes,recipe,imagepath,userID) VALUES ('misbah', 'ss','1','1','s','','')

Comment: Do you see the problem, your session is not registered or it is but it is a null value, as is the img path. Look into your code and make sure that your session is being filled, otherwise, it is null.

Comment: I am assuming you are getting your session['user_id'] from another mysqli query, check that and make sure it is properly shoing the userid and properly making it the value of the session. Also, make sure your sessions are started before doing any of that `session_start()`.

Comment: the session is starting on a separate file linked to this one called checklog.php, i have echo out the query and the user id elsewhere on the page and it is showing fine so a bit confused

Comment: Then the last thing to check is the exact place it is adding user_id to the `$_SESSION['user_id'] = "";` Look there and see what is happening, because your session is null for user_id.

Comment: By chance at the end of that attached file do you destroy the session? If so you need to remove any where that you are emptying or destroying sessions. Do a search for all instances of `$_SESSION['user_is']` and double check that you are no redefining it at all, ie using = instead of == on an if statement.

Comment: Also, can you please check that your session is spelled correct the same os the rest in this instance of it. Sometimes it happens

Comment: When i echo out $SESSION['userid'] it returns the username which is text although when i check the database the coloumn only contains numbers??

Comment: The you are defining your session with the wrong fetch_array column. Double check that. IE .. userid = 3 username=denevr, maybe the got mixed up when you defined your session, or something like that.

Comment: i've started another query as you solved my initial problem cheers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456895/trying-to-upload-user-id-to-database-session-returning-userid-as-null

Comment: Thanks, and thank you for accepting my answer and one upping it. Cheers, I love this site so far!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, userid value wrapped with in quotes.  If Userid  column datatype is int then you need make sure you have value in the session handler value and if your session userid value is not an integer then it may also gives the error.

```
     $query = "INSERT INTO `recipename` (mealname,ingredients,hours,minutes,r ecipe,imagepath,userID)VALUES ('$mealname', '$ingredients','$hours','$minutes','$recipe','$image','" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "')";
```