# Trying to upload user id to database, Session returning userid as null?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a separate file called checklog.php which contains my session details

```
<?php
        session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
            $_SESSION = array();
            header('location: login.php');
        }
?>
```

and my main upload page where recipes are being uploaded to the database i'm trying to post the user id into the db but to no avail

```
<?php
require_once ("checklog.php");
require_once ("function.php");
include_once ("home_start_logged.php");
require_once ("db_connect.php"); 
//get form data//
$_SESSION['userid']== $_POST['userid'];
$upload = trim($_POST['Upload']);
$mealname = trim($_POST['mealname']);
$ingredients = trim($_POST['ingredients']);
$hours = trim($_POST['hours']);
$minutes = trim($_POST['minutes']);
$recipe = trim($_POST['recipe']);

echo $_SESSION['userid'];
if(trim($_POST['Submit']) =="Upload"){
if($db_server){
    //clean the input now we have a db connection//
    $mealname = clean_string($db_server, $mealname);
    $ingredients = clean_string($db_server, $ingredients);
    $hour = clean_string($db_server, $hour);
    $minutes = clean_string($db_server, $minutes);
    $recipe = clean_string($db_server, $recipe);
    $ingredients = clean_string($db_server, $ingredients);
    $image = clean_string($db_server,$image);
    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database) ;


//check whether the recipe exists//
$query= "SELECT mealname FROM `recipename` WHERE mealname='$mealname'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $message = "Meal already exists. Please try again.";
    }else{
        //upload recipe to database//
        $query = "INSERT INTO `recipename` (
                      mealname, ingredients, hours, minutes, recipe, 
                      imagepath, userID) VALUES ('$mealname',
                      '$ingredients','$hours','$minutes','$recipe',
                      '$image','" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "')";
        echo query;
    mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or 
        die("Insert failed. ". mysqli_error($db_server));
    }
```

my form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <li>
Meal Name
    <input type="text" name="mealname" />
    </li>
    <li>
Ingredients
    <input type="text" name="ingredients" />
    </li>
    <li>
Cooking Time
    <input type="number" name="hours" placeholder="Hours" />
    <input type="number" name="minutes" placeholder="Minutes" />
     </li>
     <li>
 Recipe
 <input type="text" name="recipe"/>
     </li>
     <li>
Have you got a photo?
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" size="10"/>
    </li>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" />  
  </form>
```

this is my login form where I define $_SESSION

```
<?php
require_once ("function.php");
    //get form data//
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    //start session//
    if ($username&&$password) {
        session_start();
        require_once("db_connect.php"); 
        //clean the input now we have a db connection//
        $username = clean_string($db_server, $username);
        $password = clean_string($db_server, $password);
        $repeatpassword = clean_string($db_server, $repeatpassword) ;
        mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database) ;
        //check whether the username exists//
        $query="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$username'";
        $result=mysqli_query($db_server, $query) ;
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $db_username = $row['Username'];
            $db_password = $row['Password'];
            $db_id = $row['userid'];

            if ($username==$db_username&&salt($password)==$db_password){
                $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                $_SESSION['userid']=$db_id;
                $_SESSION['logged']="logged";
                header ('Location: phpdatabase.php');
            }else{
                $message = "<h1>Incorrect Password!</h1>";
            }
        }else{
            $message = "<h1>That user does not exist!</h1>" .
                            "Please <a href='login.php'>try again</a>";
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        require_once ("db_close.php");
    }else{
        $message = "<h1>Please enter a valid username/password</h1>";
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Fud.</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css" />

</head> 
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action='login.php' method='post'>
    Username:<input type='text' name='username'><br />
    Password: <input type='password' name='password'><br /> 
   <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' />
   <input name='reset' type='reset' value='reset' />

   <h4><a href='register.php'>Register</a></h4>

</form>
       <?php echo $message; ?>
```

Comment: You have to start your session in your second file too. Also you should remove `$_SESSION = array();` and after `header()` you should insert a line with `exit;`

Comment: `$_POST['userid']` what form are you talking about? the form in the question has no such element.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing appears in your form named `userid` so when you set :

```
$_SESSION['userid']= $_POST['userid'];
```

`$_POST['userid']` is empty, maybe somewhere else you have the user id set in $_SESSION already, if that is the case you don't need to set anything new, just use that.

Comment: going to be honest im really confused at the moment the form has stopped uploading anything to the database now

Comment: exactly you are right, normally `userid` is stored in session at login validation time.

Comment: Misdigest the $_POST variable contains all the named items in the form you submitted, userid isn't a name field in your form so it won't be in the $_POST variable. Once you are getting the userid successfully, probably from $_SESSION if you stored it there when they logged in, than try echoing your query string and running it directly in mysql workbench to see more detailed errors.

Answer (score 0):

No `session_start();` in your second file.

To access the Session global you need to start the session.

use

```
$_SESSION['userid']= $_POST['userid'];
```

not

```
$_SESSION['userid']== $_POST['userid'];
```

Comment: i've just tried this still sending a null value to my database

Comment: @misdigest try `echo $_POST['userid'];` and post what you get

Comment: whole pile of nothing

Comment: if you get nothing  when you `echo $_POST['userid'];` then you should check your form. Mind showing the code?

Comment: ive tried this but now although it confirms everything has been uploaded, nothing is added to the database

Comment: no problem form looks like this check the question for an edit

Comment: there is no field for userid in the form.. How will the form post the userid then?

Comment: the user is logged in so i thought it should be able to upload the userid from the session?

Comment: @misdigest you have to put `userid` in session while authenticating user and then re-use it where needed check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving value from `$_POST` array to `$_SESSION` but there is no such element as `$_POST['userid']` in your requesting form.

**Solution:** It will be best to authenticate user by logging him/her in first. Once the user is logged in you can save userid in your session which will be accessible in every page throughout your session.

Assuming your login form has a text field name `userid`. Put this in your login check file after starting your session and validating user.

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['userid'];
```

Now in your page where you are inserting data into database remove line saying

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['userid'];
```

Comment: user id is auto incremented when they register i'm just trying to upload that value from my user database into my recipe database

Comment: I have edit the original question with my login form , so are you saying i have to call to the session defined in there?

Comment: you can get last auto increment id using `mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);` at registration time after insert then store it in `$_SESSION['userid'];`

Comment: yes but your login page seems correct just remove `$_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['userid'];` from your main recipe insertion page.